# how to exclude Master branch on a push event

Tags: github

I have a GitHub Action workflow that I want to run on a push to any of the branches in my repository with an exception of 'Master. I don't want the workflow to run on a push to master branch but run on push to other branches in my repository. Please how can I specify that in the workflow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your Github Actions workflows file you can specify

```
name: Deploy staging
on:
  push:
    branches-ignore:
      - master
```

You can also explicitly include branches you want by doing the following:

```
name: Deploy staging
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - develop
```

Changing or adding branches to include the relevant branches that you want. In this manner, workflows will only run to those elected branches.

Here is the relevant section of the [Github docs on branches and tags](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-workflows/workflow-syntax-for-github-actions#example-including-branches-and-tags)